# Proof explanation of a property of the $\psi_1$ function (Stein and Shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm having difficulties understanding the justification of a step in Lemma 2.4 (Complex Analysis Stein and Shakarchi, p.192). In the last step of the proof, why are we allowed to switch the order of the improper integral and the infinite sum?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds = x \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\Lambda(n) \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{(x/n)^s}{s(s+1)}ds$$

(note: we know that $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$)

Do we need to prove the existence of the integral on the LHS first? in the proof the authors mentioned nothing about the existence and straight on switched the order of the integral and sum. I was considering to use the Lebesgue condition to justify this switching, namely:

$$\int\sum |f_n| < \infty \implies \int\sum f_n = \sum\int f_n.$$
(for sigma-finite spaces). But I don't see how to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $\sigma$-finitude is not necessary in the theorem you state

Comment: @FShrike Why is that the case? if we want to use the lemmas from Lebesgue (Fubini) we need that both spaces are sigma finite, right?

Comment: Sum-integral exchange can be handled by the dominated convergence theorem, as a sum can be cast as a sequential limit

Comment: @FShrike that makes sense, but I think dominated convergence needs a stronger assumption that simply $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$ right? we need to find a function $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g$ and $g$ is integrable.

Comment: $|f_n|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n\right|<\sum_n|f_n|=g$

Comment: @FShrike I see, now I understand, thank you. Do you know why we're justified to switch the integral and sum with the equation above? I'm clueless as to how to verify the condition $\int \sum |f_n|$, or maybe there's another easier/direct way to see this? since the authors didn't really say anything maybe its trivial?

Answer (score 1):

From the growth of $\zeta'$ and $1/\zeta$ given in Propositions 2.7(of chapter 6) and Proposition 1.6, we see that the left hand side integral is well-defined. To change the sum and integral, we need to show that $$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{x^c}{\left|s(s+1)\right|}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^c}ds < \infty.$$ This is done by interchanging(which is possible for non-negative case), since $$x^c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^c}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{ds}{\left|s(s+1)\right|} = A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^c} < \infty.$$

Comment: What is $A$ in our case?

Comment: $\int_{c-i \infty}^{c + i \infty} ds/|s(s+1)|$ is not finite right? since similarly we know $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} 1/t^2 dt$ is not finite

Comment: It is finite, since there is $c>1$. Near $t = \pm\infty$ the integral is bounded by $1/t^2$, and near $c$(where $t$ become small), the integral is bounded by $1/c(c+1)<1/2$.